# the focus() function does not see the existing element

Tags: javascript, html

I have two lines of code:

`1` `console.log(currentPopup.querySelector("input"));`
`2` `currentPopup.querySelector("input").focus();`

Before calling the `focus()` function on an element (`input`), I want to check if it (`input`) even exists (line 1).

In console I get the following:

[image]

This means that the element I need exists and I can call the `focus()` function on it, but the function does not work
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `does not work` can you be more specific?  I copied your code, added a "currentPopup" element, and I'm not having any problems.  https://jsfiddle.net/btugr3sy/

Comment: I assume there is no  error in the console? What code do you call to set the focus? (aka what action calls this code)